# What's the deal with Chrysaor's mask?

Tags: percy-jackson, greek-myth, the-heroes-of-olympus

In *The Mark of Athena*, we see the villain Chrysaor, also referred to as the Golden Boy. He wore a gorgon mask that covered his face. When Frank Zhang attacked him (in the form of a grizzly bear), he swiped off his mask. Chrysaor screamed, covered his face, and dove into the sea.

Why? Why would he cover his face? What was under the mask? Answers from Rick Riordan's books and/or Greek mythology are welcome (so anything from the old stories works, too).

Comment: Not revealed yet, as far as I can tell. The wiki just says that it's not known

Comment: If a grisly grizzly bear swiped a mask off your face you might scream in horror, and be pleasently surprised that your face still worked well enough to scream with.  And you might not know how badly your face had been damaged and so tried covering it to prevent losss of blood and face parts.  And if a grizzly bear attacked you diving into the sea to escape might seem like a good idea.  I haven read the books, but your description doesn't make it seem like there was anything that particularly needed explaining.

Comment: @M.A.Golding - He screams, covers his face (Phantom-of-the-Opera-style) and then runs away.

Comment: I also doubt there's enough from mythology to actually shed any light on this. Chrysaor wasn't very prominent, unlike his sister.

Comment: @Carson Yeah, Percy mentions in the book that Chrysaor didn't *have* any legends, but I thought I'd ask anyway

Comment: Can't edit my comment but I meant brother not sister when referring to Pegasus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## There aren't any answers

As you mentioned in the comments, Chrysaor doesn't *have* any legends.

> Little is known about Chrysaor; he was considered a stout-hearted warrior, and his name means "he who bears a golden sword". He did not have a major role in Greek mythology.
>
> *Source: https://www.greekmythology.com/Myths/Creatures/Chrysaor/chrysaor.html*

In fact, even the bit Rick Riordan wrote about him in *The Mark of Athena* is stretching the myths; there's no evidence that he ever controlled the dolphin warriors created by Dionysus.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that Chrysaor covered his face because of three reasons:

- He was extremely ugly and disformed, so he hides his face in a mask.
- Because he was paying tribute to his mother and rebelling against people.
- He could turn people to stone like his mother and so he wears the mask to make sure that he doesn't petrify his prisoners before slaying them.

Also, maybe he wants to leave a mark in the world, because he is not as recognized as his brother, Pegasus. So he decided to wear a golden mask to make sure that people recognized him. His name means "the golden one". Or something like that. I forgot the real meaning. But that is why I think that Chrysaor wears a golden mask.

I've looked up why he wears a mask, but the resources are few and the ones I found are not very good. I'm just giving ideas on why he wears a mask. I'm a mythology nerd, and I know a lot about these things, so I gave my best answer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have evidence for any of your theories?  We prefer answers based on canon, in-universe sources over pure guesswork.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).